# Preannihilator of the annihilator

Tags: linear-algebra, solution-verification, proof-writing

I'm working through some linear algebra exercises and have a question regarding a proof of a statement about annihilators. My course seems much more elementary than what I've found on this forum about annihilators so let me state the definition I have.

> Let $S \subseteq V$ be a subspace of a vector space $V$, we define the annihilator of $S$ as $S^° =\{ \varphi \in V^* \mid \varphi(s)=0 \ \forall s \in S\}$, where $V^*$ denotes the dual space of $V$.

The problem statement is the following

> Let $V$ be a finite dimentional vector space, and $S$ a subspace of $V$. Let $T=\{v \in V \ \mid \varphi(v) =0 \  \forall \varphi \in S^°\}. $ Prove $S=T$

The inclusion $S \subseteq T$ follows straight from the definition of annihilator. My problem is that for the other inclusion, the provided proof in the book I'm reading seems much more complicated than what I came up with, so I'm worried I might have overlooked something in my attempt. What I've tried is the following:

> Let $B_s =\{v_1,...,v_r\}$ be a basis of S, and $B=\{v_1,...,v_r,v_{r+1},...,v_n\}$ an extension to a basis of $V$. Consider $B^*=\{\varphi_1,...,\varphi_n\}$ the dual basis of $B$, that is, for each $i, j$, $\varphi_i(v_j)= 1$ if $i=j$ and $0$ if else. Let $t\in T$, then it's coordinate vector in basis $B$ is $(t)_B=(\varphi_1(t),...,\varphi_n(t))=(\varphi_1(t),...,\varphi_r(t),0,...,0)$ because for $i \geq r+1$, we have $\varphi_i\in S^°$. Then we must have $t\in S$ and $T\subseteq S$ which completes the proof.

I would very much appreciate it if someone could tell me if there's something wrong with my attempted proof, thanks!

Comment: I would generally approach this type of problem by thinking, "How can I show some arbitrary $a∈T ⇒ a∈S$?" What does $a∈T$ mean and can I use the connection between $T, S^∘, S$ to show that all $a∈T ⇒ a∈S$.

Comment: @eddie I would too! That's what I went for with my solution, and what seems more natural to me. It's why I'm worried I might have missed something, because the book provides a proof by contradiction which seems more convoluted.

Comment: Your proof looks good to me. The only thing you might want to consider adding is how you know that $\varphi_i \in S^\circ$ for $i > r$. but that is pretty trivial. I suggest writing your proofs as if your audience were at least a chapter behind you in the text.

Comment: @PaulSinclair Great, thanks for the advice, I'll keep it in mind when writing!